# Is this the correct way to bind a textbox to a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding, sqldatasource

I was trying to use a textbox as filter for a gridview and ended up writing this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "connection string goes here"
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE area LIKE '" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
            'GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand
            SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

It works. However I feel it's too simple and unsecure. Could you please tell me how should it be done in a more "professional"(real) way?

Comment: use prepared or parameterized statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a parameterized sql statement, add a select parameter with its sql data type and a default value.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "connection string goes here"
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE area LIKE @area"
            'GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("area", DbType.String,TextBox1.Text))  
            SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute connection and query in another function called and send the sqldatasource object to it? And make it with "using" instead of "try/catch"?

Comment: you can assign a connection string and a select statement in any of the subs. i dont really get what you mean by 'send the sqldatasource object to it'. As for using a `using statement` instead of `try/catch`, you can do it but it wont let you handle the exceptions. Also for better exception handling you should handle the exceptions in each of the declarations(like `selecting`, `rowediting` etc) of both the gridview and the sqldatasource.

Answer (score 1):

In-line SQL is not secure, you are vulnerable to SQL injection, because something extremely harmful to your database could be typed into that text box and there is not checking of that value.

Read [Understanding SQL Injection and Creating SQL Injection Proof ASP.NET Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459324/Understading-SQL-Injection-and-Creating-SQL-Inject)

Use parameterized SQL or stored procedures inside of SQL Server.